# TypeError: UserAdmin() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, abstract-class, django-custom-user

I am making an abstract user in which i get this error please solve it .
i want make a custom user model django.

**Error**

```
(venv) python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mraries/Documents/shift_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mraries/Documents/shift_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/mraries/Documents/shift_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/mraries/Documents/shift_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/mraries/Documents/shift_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/mraries/Documents/shift_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/mraries/Documents/shift_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/mraries/Documents/shift_api/shift/admin.py", line 24, in <module>
    admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
  File "/home/mraries/Documents/shift_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 134, in register
    self._registry[model] = admin_class(model, self)
TypeError: UserAdmin() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

**Admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from .models import User
from . import models


def UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display = ['email', 'name']
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'field':('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal Info'), {'fields':('name',)}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields':('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')}),
        (_('Important Dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', )})
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes':('wide', ),
            'fields':('email', 'password', 'password2')
                }),
    )

admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin

# Create your models here.
class UserManger(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_field):
        """creates and save a new user"""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address")
        user= self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_field)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=225, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    object = UserManger()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

fhbuirefgbeuifbeuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuucndfbvffvbdhbvhvbbvubfufuifhfhuhdfdshfsdjhfjfhjdshfjkshfjcbjcbvfbv fvu ifuhvuihvufdg urf huhvfudv fuhfuf fdhfidhfifugf

Comment: Your pet tap-danced on your keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserAdmin` should be a class and not a function.

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    ...
```